# how to pass a value into a next iteration of array_reduce in immutable style?

Tags: php, immutability, array-reduce

I've got a two-dimensional array:

```
    $array = [
                 ['property', 'group1', 'was', 'added'],
                 ['property', 'ouch', 'was', 'removed'],
                 ['property', 'ouch', 'was', 'updated'],
                 ['property', 'group3', 'was', 'added'],
                 ['property', 'group5', 'was', 'removed'],
    ];
```

I want to eliminate those subarrays, whose second element (with index 1) coincides with second element of the folowing subarray. In my example above it's *['property', 'ouch', 'was', 'removed']* I want to remove. And I have to solve it using functional programming and without mutations.

So, I wrote this:

```
    function filter($arr)
    {
        $lineNumber = 0;
        $arrayFiltered = array_reduce($arr, function ($acc, $line) use ($arr, &$lineNumber) {
            if ((isset($arr[$lineNumber + 1][1])) and ($arr[$lineNumber + 1][1] !== $line[1])) {
                $acc[] = $line;
            } elseif ($lineNumber === count($arr) - 1) {
                $acc[] = $line;
            }
            $lineNumber++;
            return $acc;
        }, []);
        return $arrayFiltered;
     }
```

The code does its job. But my autotest is not happy: *"Should not use of mutating operators"* for the lines where we fill our **acc** and for the line where we increment **$lineNumber**.

Any advise on how to refactor it to get rid of mutations?